# Entity primary key and sequence

Tags: oracle, primary-key

i use oracle and openjpa.
i have an primary key and i want to use a sequence for its value

```
CREATE TABLE LOG (
    ID  NUMBER(10)          not null,
    TIMESTAMP               TIMESTAMP DEFAULT (SYSDATE),
    constraint PK_ID  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE ID_SEQ
 START WITH     1
 INCREMENT BY   1
 NOCACHE
 NOCYCLE;


@Entity
@Table(name="Log")
public class Log implements Serializable  {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ_GEN", sequenceName="ID_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ_GEN" )
    @Column(name="id",nullable=false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="timestamp",nullable=false)
    private Timestamp timestamp;

    public Log(){
    }

    public Log(Timestamp timestamp){
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
    ..
}

@Stateless
public class LogDAO {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="logEntityPU")
    private EntityManager em ;


    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public boolean insert(Log log){
      em.persist(log);
      return true;
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

when i check my Log object, id=0 and the timestamp is ok

but i get this error
ORA-01400: integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint.Insertion of null value not allowed

it's like jpa don't do the link with the sequence.

when i debug more, i see this error: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No active transaction for PuId=

any idea?

Comment: Before Oracle 12 you had to get the id with a command before you could use it or you need a  before insert trigger on the table which inserts the sequence for you.

Comment: tried with a trigger, same result... if i insert manually with sql plus tool, that work... so seem to have a program with the java code.

Comment: if a trigger did not work, then please provide the code.  Triggers to insert sequences do work. I have hundreds of them in an application.

Comment: problem is surely not the trigger, like i wrote, seem like a transaction problem

Comment: If you won't show the trigger code how can we tell?

Comment: if i insert manualy a value, trigger is called... problem is surely not the trigger, also, errror said transaction.... anyway the problem was the transaction and now is fixed

Answer (score 0):

A trigger like this will insert the primary key if one is not provided by the app

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER YOUR_SCHEMA.TRG_YOUR_TABLE
BEFORE INSERT 
ON YOUR_SCHEMA.YOUR_TABLE
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   PrimaryKeyId NUMBER;

BEGIN
      IF :NEW.PRIMARY_KEY_ID IS NULL THEN
         SELECT your_schema.seq_your_table.nextval
         INTO :NEW.PRIMARY_KEY_ID
         FROM dual;
      END IF;

END YOUR_SCHEMA.TRG_YOUR_TABLE;
```

Then do a

```
Select YOUR_SCHEMA.seq_your_table.currval from dual;
```

to get the value